# Two instantiations of the managed-bean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, ajax4jsf

When I access to my page for the fist time, the managed bean used by the page is instantiate two times (I pass two times in the contructor, with the same stack trace) :

```
Daemon Thread [http-127.0.0.1-8080-1] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 76 in MyController))   
    MyController.<init>() line: 76  
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 39    
    DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 27    
    Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: 513 
    Class<T>.newInstance0() line: 355   
    Class<T>.newInstance() line: 308    
    ManagedBeanBuilder(BeanBuilder).newBeanInstance() line: 186 
    ...
    pass throught two Filters (one of the filter uses Waffle and the other calls a web service...)  
    ...     
    Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Socket) line: 601    
    JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 447  
    Thread.run() line: 662
```

In the xhtml :

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName="myController"></a4j:keepAlive>
<h:form>
...
</h:form>
```

In the faces-config.xml :

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>myController</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.xx.MyController</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Why does the managed bean is instanciate two times ?

Thank you for your ideas...

Using

- jsf 1.2
- richfaces 3.3.2.SR1

Edit:
Thanks to Joeri Hendrickx, I found out that I have two differents request. So the new question is "why have I two requests when I access to my page?"

Comment: Since your bean is request-scoped, this should not be the case.  You say you have the same stacktrace twice; check if the Request object is the same.

Comment: You're right, actually it is not the same request. Indication : During the process, I pass throught two Filters (one of the filter uses Waffle and the other calls a web service...).

Comment: @Joeri: you should repost that as an answer, that it are actually two physically different requests.

Comment: @BalusC For sure, but I am currently asking me "why have I two requests when I access to my page?". The question has just change.

Comment: That's not a JSF problem. Just install a HTTP traffic debugger like Fiddler2. May I guess that you're using Eclipse with Tomcat or JBoss and that the first request was fired right before the server is finished with starting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get two instances of a request-scoped bean, that should mean you have two requests.

Check if your browser is sending out two requests (use firebug or fiddler).  If it's sending out only one, that means your request is duplicated somewhere in the stack (porbably in a filter, or maybe even in a custom servlet).

Comment: To end this story, I could not find why there are two requests. Can be made by jsf processes. As it do not seem disturbing, I leave this problem. However, this is the first time I see this behavior is jsf. Thanks

Comment: @Jean-Charles If you're usign a full open-source stack (and I'll assume this), you should be able to track the request completely to its origin.  If it's really two seperate requests object coming in from your server (tomcat?) then it must be two requests and you should at least see this in Fiddler.  No problem is undebuggable if you have the right tools :)

Comment: Yes for sure, I agree with that ;) but I am asking me if this is realy a bug. The global behavior seems to be the good (keep alive works fine for example). Have you ever see this behavior in your application (two instanciations) ?

Comment: No; I've seen multiple accesses often enough, but never multiple instances.

Comment: Even if the problem still exists, I accept your answer because you help me to look in the right way... thanks

Comment: To conclude with this problem : The reason why there was 2 requests : `<h:graphicImage value="#{component.iconImage}" />` has sometime `""` value. In this case, a new GET request was looking for the image after the first request. 

To solve this I added `rendered="#{component.iconImage != null}"`. Thanks